# Save volume peak to file in qt5

Tags: mp3, qt5

I have mp3 files and i whant to create peak widget, but i dont wont create it on live. 
I whant create peak text file (format is not important) and write ~100 average value of volume in the file.

How i get voiume of mp3 samples to calculate middle volume portion songs on qt5 and write it to file?

*I try QAudioProbe but i not understand how probe autosamples*
*libsbdfile don`t support mp3 and i*

I want to do everything for maximum Qt without third-party libraries

Answer (score 0):

It is always difficult to say 'it cannot be done'... the usual problems with negative proofs. However, I don't think you can do this with Qt. Qt does know far less about multimedia than you might think. It uses 3rd party code to play audio and video. Qt certainly does not understand anything about mp3 encoding. Not even wav... Want "presumptive evidence"? Look in the Qt examples: examples/multimedia/spectrum. And examples/multimedia/spectrum/app/wavfile.cpp. Everything is done 'manually'. No special Qt api for what you want.